# How to show bullet on hover state amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts4

I am plotting amcharts 4 , I need to show the bullet on hover state only.
I have found the link which is doing this .

Link   : https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/qvdrwa

The problem is that I have thousands of data points When dealing with a large number of data points, the multiple bullets appearing upon hover might be due to the rapid or multiple firing of hover event.

How to make sure one bullet should be appear

```
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 450,
  "value2": 362,
  "value3": 699
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
  "value": 269,
  "value2": 450,
  "value3": 841
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
  "value": 700,
  "value2": 358,
  "value3": 699
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 4),
  "value": 490,
  "value2": 367,
  "value3": 500
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
  "value": 500,
  "value2": 485,
  "value3": 369
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 6),
  "value": 550,
  "value2": 354,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 7),
  "value": 420,
  "value2": 350,
  "value3": 600
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
//categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series.name = name;
  //series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  
  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
  bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
  bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
  bullet.fillOpacity = 0;
  bullet.strokeOpacity = 0;
  
  var bulletState = bullet.states.create("hover");
  bulletState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
  bulletState.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;
}

createSeries("value", "Series #1");
createSeries("value2", "Series #2");
createSeries("value3", "Series #3");

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```